# Beginner's apache mod_rewrite assistance

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am not really familiar with apache `mod_rewrite`.

I have url parameters such as `{domain}/index.php?blog=5`

I simply want to make it `{domain}/home.php?client=5`

Is it a task as simple as it sounds and can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The following *might* work, give it a try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} client=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{REMOTE_HOST}/index.php?blog=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems pretty simple, to be honest — once you get your head into `mod_rewrite`, it's not that complex.

It sounds like you want to add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.php?blog=(.+)$ /home.php?client=$1
```

to your configuration.

Some caveats:

- If you are putting this in a `.htaccess` file, then remove the `/` from the `RewriteRule` line.
- If you want to make this case-insensitive, add `[NC]` to the end of that same line.
- If you want users to see the URL change (so sending a `302 Found` redirection to the browser), then add `[R]` to the end of the `RewriteRule` line.
- If you want both a `302 Found` and for the URL to be case-sensitive, combine the two instructions as `[NC,R]` at the end of the `RewriteRule` line.

It's definitely worth reading the [`mod_rewrite` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), but the rule above should be all you need for this use-case.